# SharePoint Document Libraries - "Date Created" field

Tags: document-library

I have a request from a SharePoint user to show the "Date Created" column in her Document Library.

Trouble is,

I cannot find a way to show the date of when the Document was added to the library.  I tried adding the standard column "Date Created" but it is blank for all documents listed there already, and uploading/editing a document prompts you to manually choose a date.

I want the date when document was added to the Document Library to be shown automatically.

Is there a way?

Comment: Wow asked 11 years ago! I tried to follow the tips on this answer and it worked however it doesn't automatically add the dated added/uploaded. I have to add it manually which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding "**Date Created**" from "`Document Library Settings > Add from existing site columns`", go to "`Settings > Create View`" the field you want is just plain "**Created**", you should see it in the list of available columns.

Once you name this view, you can save it and make it the default view for this document library.

Comment: Thanks - sharepoint needs some work in the intuitive dept.

Comment: haha - true enough!

Answer (score 0):

The Created column can be displayed by "+ Add column" > "Show/hide columns" > checking "Created".

Please see the screenshots.

The Created column already exists (so we don't have to create one), but it is hidden.

[image]

[image]